# Is it possible to make method accessible at specific API level?

Tags: android

Is it possible to mark methods in a class accessible at specific API level?
For example, I have two methods: `foo1(int param1)` and `foo2(int param1, int param2)`. Id'like to make `foo2` method requiring specific API level. Let it be 19, so that if I use min sdk 8, I'll receive an error about API requirements. Of cource, I can always do **if (api_level == 19) foo2(); else foo1()**. But I'd like some protection to exclude possible errors.

Comment: you can use annotation above the method `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.XXXX)` and Lint will warn you when using it in pre XXXX api version

Comment: @MoshErsan Yep, this seems to be exactly what is needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am actually doing something similar I would recommend using switch case using version build Here is an example (I am just listing all of the version levels not recommending at add all of them just the one(s) you want.

```
switch (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE: // API level 1
        // Code or method goes here
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE_1_1: // API level 2
        Toast.makeText(this, "Base update version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE: // API level 3
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cupcake version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.CUR_DEVELOPMENT: // API level 4
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cur development version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT: // API level 5
        Toast.makeText(this, "Donut version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR: // API level 6
        Toast.makeText(this, "Eclair version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_0_1: // API level 7
        Toast.makeText(this, "Eclair 0 1 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1: // API level 8
        Toast.makeText(this, "Eclair MR1 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO: // API level 9
        Toast.makeText(this, "Froyoooo version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD: // API level 10
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gingerbread version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1: // API level 11
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gingerbread MR1 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB: // API level 12
        Toast.makeText(this, "Honeycomb version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1: // API level 13
        Toast.makeText(this, "Homecomb MR1 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Honeycomb MR2 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH: // API level 14
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ice Cream Sandwich version",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1: // API level 15
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ice Cream Sandwich MR1 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN: // API level 16
        Toast.makeText(this, "Jelly Bean version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1: // API level 17
        Toast.makeText(this, "Jelly Bean MR1 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2: // API level 18
        Toast.makeText(this, "Jelly Bean MR2 version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT: // API level 19
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kitkat version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kitkat Watch version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
}
```